# Python - Mocking an object's attribute with multiple values?

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-3.x, testing, mocking

I have an object method which changes an attribute of an object. Another method (the one I'm trying to test) calls the first method multiple times and afterward uses the attribute that was modified. How can I test the second method while explicitly saying how the first method changed that attribute?

For example:

```
def method_to_test(self):
    output = []
    for _ in range(5):
        self.other_method()
        output.append(self.attribute_changed_by_other_method)
    return output
```

I want to specify some specific values that `attribute_changed_by_other_method` will become due to `other_method` (and the real `other_method` uses probabilities in deciding on how to change `attribute_changed_by_other_method`).

I'm guessing the best way to do this would be to "mock" the attribute `attribute_changed_by_other_method` so that on each time the value is read it gives back a different value of my specification. I can't seem to find how to do this though. The other option I see would be to make sure `other_method` is mocked to update the attribute in a defined way each time, but I don't know of a particularly clean way of doing this. Can someone suggest a reasonable way of going about this? Thank you much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you can actually do is use [flexmock](http://has207.github.io/flexmock/compare.html#verify-a-method-was-called-multiple-times) for `other_method`. What you can do with flexmock is set a mock on an instance of your class. Here is an example of how to use it:

```
class MyTestClass(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.my_obj = MyClass()
        self.my_obj_mock = flexmock(self.my_obj)

    def my_test_case(self):
        self.my_obj_mock.should_receive('other_method').and_return(1).and_return(2).and_return(3)
        self.my_obj.method_to_test()
```

So, what is happening here is that on your instance of `MyClass`, you are creating a flexmock object out of `self.my_obj`. Then in your test case, you are stating that when you make your call to `method_to_test`, you should receive `other_method`, and each call to it should return `1, 2, 3` respectively.

Furthermore, if you are still interested in knowing how to mock out `attribute_changed_by_other_method`, you can use Mock's [PropertyMock](https://bradmontgomery.net/blog/how-world-do-you-mock-name-attribute/):

Hope this helps. Let me know how it goes!

Comment: The PropertyMock got me what I was looking for (using the `type()` approach given in the link you posted for it).

Answer (score 1):

For anyone still looking for a straightforward answer, this can be done easily with `PropertyMock` as the accepted answer suggests. Here is one way to do it.

```py
from unittest.mock import patch, PropertyMock


with patch("method_your_class_or_method_calls", new_callable=PropertyMock) as mock_call:
        mock_call.side_effect = [111, 222]
        class_or_method()
```

Each subsequent call of that patched method will return that list in sequence.